# Montar uma unica string com varias strings de uma ArrayList em Java

Tags: java, array, string, lista

Como posso pegar de forma simplificada várias Strings de uma ArrayList e unir em apenas uma váriavel do tipo String? Sou novo no Java e estou com dificuldade para concluir essa alteração de forma simplificada, evitando linhas de códigos longos e sem necessidade.

```
 List<String> fields_list = new ArrayList<String>();

 Saída: ["Campo1, Campo2, Campo3"]
```

Deverá ficar dessa forma a minha variável do tipo String:

```
String fields = "Campo1 Campo2 Campo3";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o método [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) da classe *String*:

```
String fields = String.join(" ", fields_list);
```

<sub>**Nota:** Necessita JAVA 8</sub>

Comment: Se ele estiver usando java 8 tudo bem. Caso contrário não vai funcionar. Você poderia incluir este detalhe na sua resposta :)

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Sim, estava agora a editar para colocar link para a documentação. Vou no entanto deixar isso mais claro.

Comment: Não estava usando Java 8 Support, acabei de implementar no meu Eclipse: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds/.

Comment: @ramaral quer incorporar minha resposta na sua e eu apago?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Apagar porquê? A sua resposta é válida(votei nela), acho que deve mantê-la.

Comment: @ramaral Porque o autor já marcou a sua como correta, então se você incorpora a minha na sua fica uma resposta válida pra qualquer pessoa com o mesmo problema :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro O AP marcou a minha como a resposta aceite, a que melhor servia para ele, não quer dizer com isso que só ela está correcta ou que é a melhor. Outra pessoa que não esteja a usar JAVA 8 irá ler a sua resposta e será a sua que lhe servirá e por certo votará nela. Se eu incorporar a sua resposta na minha passarei eu a receber todos os créditos o que não seria justo. O que melhor indica se uma resposta é boa ou não é o número de votos que recebeu e não a marca de aceite.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize um `StringBuilder` para agrupar seus valores e o for para iterar sobre a lista, exemplo:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : fields_list)
{
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append(" ");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
```

#### Não concatene as strings dessa forma `s1 + s2`

Desse jeito pra cada concatenada o compilador gera uma nova instância do `StringBuilder` de forma implícita, então a melhor maneira é utilizando apenas **1** conforme o exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Ou você pode fazer um loop:

```
String listString;
for (String s : list)
{
    listString += s + " ";
}
```

Ou você pode usar o StringUtils, que fica no [commons-lag](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

```
listString = StringUtils.join(list, " ");
```

Comment: Em concatenaçõs dentro de loops deve-se usar StringBuilder ou StringBuffer